# When can you use the 'as' operator?

Tags: casting, kotlin

I have the following program:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var a: Int
    var b = 23.5
    a = b as Int
    println(a)
}
```

If I run it, the program throws a `java.lang.ClassCastException` exception.

Since the data types used in Kotlin are represented as objects, I can understand why it is not possible to frivolously cast them like I have, and instead should use the built-in conversion methods associated with each type or the "safe" `as?` operator -- but then this brings the question: when can (or should) you use the `as` operator?

Comment: Don't mix up casting and converting. `as` is used for casting objects. For instance, a method returns an interface or a super class but you need to get the concrete type. Sometimes the compiler doesn't know about the type, but you do, so you cast it. If Kotlin didn't have smart casting you'd need to use `as` a lot more.

Comment: So let's imagine I am compiler and you are trying to cast `cat` to `helicopter`, what you expect me to do ?

Comment: I'd expect you to have the  _smart convert_ feature built in :)

Comment: ++ What you actually need to use here is b.toInt()

Comment: And now do you care to explain how on earth should I convert cat to helicopter in a smart way ?

Comment: Hell, let your imagination run wild. It's not "basic conversion", it's "smart conversion": https://metro.co.uk/2015/10/01/man-who-turned-his-dead-cat-into-a-drone-now-plans-to-create-a-cow-helicopter-5416891/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181496/discussion-between-matt-and-karma-maker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin compiler's smart casts are pretty smart, so in most cases you don't need explicit casting. This code in Java:

```
Object foo = "foo";
if (foo instanceof String) {
  String fooString = (String) foo;
  System.out.println(fooString.length);
}
```

would translate to this Kotlin code:

```
val foo: Any = "foo"
if (foo is String) {
  println(foo.length)
}
```

However, `as` and `as?` are still relevant, e.g.:

```
fun test(foo: Any) {
  val fooString = foo as? String ?: throw IllegalArgumentException()
  ...
}
```

Overall, rely on smart casts as much as you can and leave `as` and `as?` for specific cases.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `b` is a `Double` floating-point value, not an `Int`.  (As other answers have pointed out.)  To convert it, you'd need to use something like `b.toInt()`.

Your program doesn't convert it, because **Kotlin's `as` operator doesn't *change* the value into a new type; instead it tells the compiler that the value is *already* of the required type.**  That's called a *cast*.

So for example, if I have:

```
val n: Number = 4
```

Then the type of `n` is `Number`.  Its current value is actually an `Int` (which is a subclass of `Number`).  So in this case I can cast it to `Int`, e.g.:

```
val i = n as Int
```

after which the compiler will *treat* it like an `Int`.

(This particular case is a *down-cast*, because `Int` is below `Number` in the class hierarchy.  In general, up-casts are safe but down-casts and others aren't.  If you had initialised `n` with a floating-point number instead, then its value would be of type `Double`, which is another subclass of `Number`, and not an `Int`; the program would fail at run-time and throw a `ClassCastException`, as you saw.  That's why Kotlin also has a safe-cast operator, `as?`, which gives null instead of the exception.)

The Kotlin compiler is very smart, and most of the time it already knows what type a value can be, so casting isn't needed very often.  There can still be occasions when you know something the compiler doesn't, and a cast is appropriate; but too many of them can be a ‘code smell’ indicating that there may be a better approach.